# how to create a dynamic array of functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to initialize a array of functions dynamically,

**Example :**

Transform the following code :

```
$filter('orderBy')(datas, 
    [
        function (obj) {
             return filterTable(obj, sortInfos.fields[0]);
        },
        function (obj) {
             return filterTable(obj, sortInfos.fields[1]);
        },
        function (obj) {
             return filterTable(obj, sortInfos.fields[2]);
        },
        function (obj) {
             return filterTable(obj, sortInfos.fields[3]);
        }
    ], 
    revert);
```

To :

`$filter('orderBy')(datas, myArrayOfFunction, revert);`

Comment: Don't repeat yourself

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I have edited my question,  I hope that it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function createMyFuntion(sortInfoIndex) {
    return function(obj) { return filterTable(obj, sortInfos.fields[sortInfoIndex]); };
}

var myArrayOfFunction = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    myArrayOfFunction.push(createMyFuntion(i))
}

$filter('orderBy')(datas, myArrayOfFunction, revert);
```

Comment: But how can I pass the "obj" to createMyFuntion ?

Comment: *But how can I pass the "obj" to createMyFuntion ?* - `obj` is an argument of a function. So these functions should be called like this: `myArrayOfFunction[1](myObj)` in `$filter('orderBy')`.

Comment: All interfaces are still same. I have only wrapped your copy-pasted functions in array to `createMyFuntion` and `for` loop.

Comment: I could not do it :( ... can you write all the solution please ?